# Python simultaneous variable incrementation

Tags: python, variables, simultaneous

Currently, I'm trying to simultaneously redefine two variables in python. For example, I have the base case

```
 p = 3
 q = 2
```

and I want to redefine p and q such that

```
 p = p+2q
```

and

```
 q = p+q
```

Therefore, the tuples of p and q should be (p,q) = (3,2) then (7,5) then (17,15), and so on. I'm not sure how to redefine these variables simultaneously.

Of course, the following code would work:

```
 p = 2
 q = 3
 temp = [0,0]

 while True:
    temp[0] = p + 2q
    temp[1] = p+q
    p = temp[0]
    q = temp[1]
    print(p,q)
```

But I was hoping to avoid the `temp` list. Is there a prettier, more python-esque way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> p = 2
>>> q = 3
>>> p, q = p + 2 * q, p + q
>>> print p
8
>>> print q
5
>>>
```

You can also add optional parentheses:

```
(p, q) = (p + 2 * q, p + q)
```

Comment: Yea I always like to add the parentheses just for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 5):

See the code below

```
p = 2
q = 3

while True:
    p, q = (p + 2*q, p + q)
    print(p, q)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p = p + 2*q
q = q + p - 2*q
```

This method should work

Comment: Does it ? Have you double-checked?

Comment: Disadvantage of lesser clarity IMO. Probably a better solution for C or other languages where the tuple method is not available.

Comment: @BaylesJ it's not about clarity(it wouldn't not work in C too), here when python goes to the 2nd statement the value of `p` has already changed and now `q` will have a value as per the new `p`.

Comment: @PierreGM: I know it's ugly and the order is important. To be honest I didn't know about p,q = (f(p,q),g(p,q)) execute with the same environment. I'm glad I learnt a new thing :)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, I think it's clearer with the edit: this example does work (now) due to eliminating the offset added to p. I just think it's less obvious what is going on, so even though it is correct I wouldn't do this in Python (other languages possible).